# Ruby method arguments transition

Tags: ruby, argument-passing

This is source code of `HTTPClient`:

```
def post(uri, *args, &block)
   request(:post, uri, argument_to_hash(args, :body, :header, :follow_redirect), &block)
end
```

I made following wrapper:

```
def post(uri, *args, &block)
  http.post(uri, args, &block)
rescue Exception => ex
  log_exception ex
end
```

And try to pass parameters:

```
httpclient.post 'url', xml_data, 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
my_proxy.post 'url', xml_data, 'Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
```

In first case HTTPclient receives following args:

```
[
    "my xml text",
    {"Content-Type"=>"application/xml"}
]
```

In second case:

```
[
  [
    "my xml text",
    {"Content-Type"=>"application/xml"}
  ]
]
```

How to pass arguments in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def post(uri, *args, &block)
  http.post(uri, *args, &block)
  # ...
```

Note the asterisk in the second line (or the absence thereof, in your code). That is the "splat" operator, which unpacks arrays into separate arguments in method calls, and packs arguments into one array in method definitions. You pack arguments in your method definition (so your `args` is an array of arguments), but then pass that array to `post`, which does not expect an array, without the unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
def proxy(uri, *args, &block)
  http.post(uri, *args, &block)
  # ...
```

should do the trick, essentially "unsplatting" (`*` is the splat operator) the args-array.